# String variable with letters and numbers: different lengths

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a string variable composed of letters and numbers, of different length. I have already separated the Code variable into 2 separate variables:

```
Code_numeric = str_sub(Code, 2),
Code_string =str_sub(Code, 1, 1)
```

However, my approach is flawed, because both X022 and X22 and end up having 22 as their numeric values. I need both Code_string and Code_numeric to be accurate so I can filter the data accordingly.

So... how do I go about mutating X09, X22, and X189(using tidyverse or dyplr) to being 09, 220, and 189 respectively? That way.. I can successfully flag rows with Codes X00-X22 as an example, using the following code:

```
flag = case_when(Code_string =="X" & Code_numeric %in% c(09, 100:129, 13:14, 150:189)  ~ 1,
                       TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
```

Thanks in advance!

I have already tried the following approach, but it's not producing the output I'm expecting:

```
Code_numeric = str_sub(Code, 2),
Code_string =str_sub(Code, 1, 1)
```

I get the following output:

| Code | Code_numeric |
| --- | --- |
| X09 | 9 |
| X22 | 22 |
| X189 | 189 |

I expect the following output (type: NUMERIC):

| Code | Code_numeric |
| --- | --- |
| X09 | 09 |
| X22 | 22 |
| X189 | 189 |

OR

| Code | Code_numeric |
| --- | --- |
| X09 | 9 |
| X22 | 220 |
| X189 | 189 |

Comment: If I define `Code = c("X09", "X22", "X189")` then `str_sub(Code, start = 2)` gives `"09"  "22"  "189"` as a result, like you want. If you are losing leading 0s it seems like maybe you are adding an `as.numeric` or `as.integer` in somewhere, which you shouldn't do if you want to keep leading 0s.

Comment: If you need more help, please share your input reproducibly so we can make sure there isn't anything going on with weird classes or data structures. `dput(your_data[1:3, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 3 rows of your data frame `your_data` and will include all class and structure information (assuming you've got a data frame since you have the `dplyr` tag and you talk about "mutating", even though all your code looks like it's working on vectors not in a data frame...)

Comment: Hi George,

Yes, I did convert the code_numeric variable using the as.numeric command, because I want to be able to filter across a range of numbers; e.g Code_string="X" and Cod_numeric %in% c(13:14)

flag = case_when(Code_string =="X" & Code_numeric %in% c(09, 100:129, 13:14, 150:189) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%

Is that possible?

Comment: `9` is a number, `"09"` is a string. You can choose between `numeric` class and leading 0s, but you can't have both--at least not in the same cell.

Comment: Is it possible to tell R to add a zero before 9? So the output would be a numeric 09

Comment: No. `9` is a number, "09" is a string. You could have a string column with the leading 0s and a numeric column with numbers. But if you test `"09" == 09`, the answer is `FALSE`. (Contrast with `"9" == 9` is `TRUE`.)

Comment: If you give us more context for what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps we can help. `c(09, 100:129, 13:14, 150:189)` is interpreted by the R parser the same as `c(9, 100:129, 13:14, 150:189)` (with a `9` not an `09` at the start). It should work fine with your numeric version. If you share the input reproducibly with `dput()` and show the desired output (the final output, not just the intermediate result for this approach) it would be less of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) and we can help you achieve the goal.

Comment: I'm trying to utilize a string variable with letters and numbers to extract specific records. Here's the issue I'm running into: lets say that I'm trying to extract records with Code=X020-X050 or Code=X20, when I run the following script:

Code_numeric = as.numeric(str_sub(Code, 2)),
Code_string =str_sub(Code, 1, 1)

and try to filter records: flag = case_when(Code_string =="X" & Code_numeric %in% c(020:050) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%

The above code doesn't work because 020-050 under the variable Code_numeric have been turned into 20-50, etc., so I miss codes 020-050. Does that may sense?

Comment: I'm very confused by your data structures - you haven't posted anything including class information so it's not at all clear how much you're using data frames vs just vectors (maybe you used the horrid `attach()` at some point? That would certainly confuse things...). You seem to be posting code snippets, several times you post a line of code that ends in `%>%`, which is confusing too. It would help a lot if you would share input reproducibly with `dput()`. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for example, for the first 10 rows. The `dput()` result is copy/pasteable and includes class information.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating the problem. Probably something like `num_codes = c(09, 100:129, 13:14, 150:189); str_codes = paste0("X", str_pad(width = 3, pad = "0"); your_data %>% filter(Code %in% str_codes)` will work. But again, the lack of copy/pasteable input and all the code snippets that we can't run because they're incomplete lines and we don't have the input makes it very hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

simply extract the string for any numerics with regex pattern. (I understand simple ones only)

with your sample and soem more added this is working:

```
codes <- c('X09','X22','X189','X2','c3',"C345")  
str_extract(string = codes,pattern = "[0-9].*")
```

output:

```
[1] "09"  "22"  "189" "2"   "3"   "345"
```

also working in a dataframe : V1 added to show a 2 column df. You can ignore it.

```
  cod <- data.frame(codes, "V1"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
cod$Code_numeric <- str_extract(string = cod$codes,pattern = "[0-9].*")
```

output

```
  codes V1 Code_numeric
1   X09  1           09
2   X22  2           22
3  X189  3          189
4    X2  4            2
5    c3  5            3
6  C345  6          345
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The Code_numeric in your output is actually a character/string variable. When converted to numeric using the as.numeric function, 09 turns into 9 again. I need the output to be NUMERIC and formatted as 09

Comment: A numeric won't have leading zeroes unless you use padding in front of them and that only for display. U cannot store numbers with 0s in front as far as I know. (Check that for urself and that's when you say something is number and not a character).  In fact the `flag= case_when` in your code should work with this. It's number as you are reading it but you are using %in% which is used for character. Have you tried the solution?

Comment: I'm trying to utilize a string variable with letters and numbers to extract specific records. Here's the issue I'm running into: lets say that I'm trying to extract records with Code=X020-X050 or Code=X20, when I run the following script:

Code_numeric = as.numeric(str_sub(Code, 2)),
Code_string =str_sub(Code, 1, 1)

and try to filter records: flag = case_when(Code_string =="X" & Code_numeric %in% c(020:050) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>%

The above code doesn't work because 020-050 under the variable Code_numeric have been turned into 20-50, etc., so I miss codes 020-050. Does that may sense?